# factorization to determine convergence/divergence

Tags: factoring

Let:

$$f(n) = n/(n^4+1)$$

if we factor f to:

$$ n/[n^3(n+1/n^3)] $$

Given that this is equivalent, we perform distribution:

$$1/[n^2(n+(1/n^3)]$$

We now have:

$$ 1/(n^3+1/n) $$

So:

$ 1/n ->$ 0 as $n -> \infty $

As well:

$ \frac 1{n^3} -> 0$ as $n -> \infty $

However, the answer uses arctangent and u substituion to solve. I did see a manipulation of arctan's integrand.

Intuitivly, I thought factoring would be easier to find how the function behaves, e.g., diverges/converges.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to show. Do you want to show $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ or something else involving the integral of $f$?

Comment: I accept the correct answer of using u^2 = n and differentiating and performing u substitution and therefore how to correctly solve it.    My confusion was factoring. Is it possible to arrive at the same answer?

Comment: You are describing how one can evaluate the integral of $f$. This has nothing to do with the limit of $f$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: f is a series from 1 to infty. Does that help? Its chapter 11.3 in the James Steward 7th edition textbook. Problem 26.

Comment: I believe that you are asking for the convergence or divergence of $\sum_n f(n)$. It would probably be best if you edit the original post and state your actual problem.

Comment: May I move on or must I continue? In terms of reputation points and h/e this site works.

Answer (score 0):

i would rewrite the term like following
$\frac{n}{n^4}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^4}}$
and we have $\frac{1}{n^3}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^4}}$ and for $n->\infty$ we obtain
$0 \cdot \frac{1}{1+0}=0$
Sonnhard.